# jQuery change variables with child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to target child elements in jQuery, make changes based on whether there are any inputs. However, this code has a few problems. First, the CSS effect on click does not apply to the textarea even when I have specified it.

Second, filling in the input field still returns the variable `truth` as false, so it does not execute the code below `$('p').html('Solid')`.

My HTML:

```
<div id="section">
    <button>Click It</button>
    <label>
        <input type="text" required="true" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <textarea required="true"></textarea>
</div>
<p></p>
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var truth = true;
    $('#section label').each(function(){
        var chooseinputs = $(this).find('input[required=true], textarea[required=true]');
        if ( !$.trim(chooseinputs.val()) ){
            $(chooseinputs).css('border', '1px solid red');
            $('p').html("Empty");
            truth = false;
        }
        if (truth)
            $('p').html("Solid!");
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97vydxz8/1/)

Comment: `<textarea>` isn't inside a `<label>` so never even gets checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just checking the first input, you need a foreach

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var truth = true;
  $('#section label> input[required=true], textarea[required=true]').each(function() {
    
    if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
      $('p').html("Empty");
      truth = false;
    }
    if (truth) {
      $('p').html("Solid!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
  <button>Click It</button>
  <label>
    <input type="text" required="true" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <textarea required="true"></textarea>
</div>
<p></p>
```